Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V etc. not working when using RemotePC from Win to Ubuntu
When using RemotePC to remote-desktoping from Win 11 to Linux Ubuntu 22.04 over the web, the keyboard isn't working well, and, in particular, Ctrl-key commands and the like don't work.
Despite being officially cross-platform, RemotePC doesn't seem to have a native feature to enable it for Win to Linux.
Is there any simple solution that allows using the keyboard properly, incl. sending Ctrl-keys and the like?
I've seen resembling questions answered for other RD software such as Remmina, but so far found no solution for RemotePC.
I'd like to use RemotePC as it ticks off a few boxes in terms of simple setup & basic features that I've so far not seen all ticked by other RD software (unless some which are even much more expensive than RemotePC).

I don't know RemotePC; that seems to be pretty "niche" when it comes to such solutions (but I'm really not of a Windows background, so that might look different for the user community of that). You say it checks many boxes, but then it stumbles on basic stuff, so hm.

Is there any simple solution that allows using the keyboard properly, incl. sending Ctrl-keys and the like?

Many!
If you just want to log in to your remote system, the GNOME environment used by Ubuntu by default does brings a remote desktop utility. I think you find it when you type "Sharing" into the application search bar when you press the windows key while logged in; if that's not it, try "Remote".
Modern GNOME can do RDP, the default windows remote desktop interface, so you can use Windows' built-in remote desktop viewer instead of third-party software; it's supported VNC in the past and probably can still. I'm sorry I can't test this right now – not in front of a system with GNOME right now.
If you don't need to connect to the currently running local session (as in: showing on the screen attached to that computer) on the remote machine, but would rather have a headless connection, you can either run gnome-remote-desktop --system (that was merged a year ago, so you might need rather modern Ubuntu), or use something like x2go-server, which allows you to start and interact with any of a number of desktop sessions remotely (but requires an X2Go client on the accessing, i.e., Windows, machine).

Top requirement: A simple tool I can readily install on Win and on Linux to then exchange a mere 1-2 strings of connection info (URL or IP or name something and a PW), and boom, connection is on, and can be re-established remotely.
Surely enough, your solution brought me to xrdp on Ubuntu, and, as always when hopeless-me tries to install even the simplest cmd thing, a failed instead of running. Which is exactly the type of reason I seek a fully integrated cross-platform solution, after year of trying this or that with usually mixed successes.

exactly why I recommended the built-in remote desktop facilities of GNOME.
